# Using jquery to hide and show php dynamicly created content "Search Results"

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic

I have a table that displays my search results, and pending if a user has a function open I want to only display 5 results per row, and the same if they have it closed I want to show 7 results. This is working fine, but the issue I am having is when I toggle the function the div is hidden or shows but the PHP content that was dynamically created is still visible. I know that the div hides or shows pending the function because I wrote static text in the dynamically create divs and pending the function the text is shown or hidden.

Question: How to hide the php content as well?
PHP content =

```
/*BIG*/
    //begin new row
    if($result_incBig == $beginRowBig){
        $b .= '<tr>';   
        //row color
        $row_color = ($color_incBig % 2) ? 'tdAltRow_A' : 'tdAltRow_B';
        if($i == ($num_qk-1)){
            $secondRowClass = 'tdAltRow_noBorder';
        }else{
            $secondRowClass = 'tdAltRow';
        }
        //increment the color of the row
        ++$color_incBig;                
    }
    $b .= '<td class="td_formTitle_noBorder" align="center" style="padding:0px; text-indent: 0;" width="165" height="115" valign="bottom">';
        $b .= '<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">';
            $b .= '<tr>';
                $b .= '<td align="center" style="height:80px; padding:4px; vertical-align:middle;">'.$appendLinkBegin.$companyPic.$appendLinkEnd.'</td>';
            $b .= '</tr>';
            $b .= '<tr>';
                $b .= '<td align="center" style="height:35px; padding:2px; vertical-align:bottom;">'.$appendLinkBegin.'<b>'.$company_name.'</b>'.$addSpace.'<br />'.$num2.' '.$resultText.$appendLinkEnd.'</td>';
            $b .= '</tr>';
        $b .= '</table>';
    $b .= '</td>';
    //end row if out of results or reached max num for row
    if($result_incBig == $endRowBig){
        $b .= '</tr>';
        $result_incBig = 0;
    }else if(($i+1) == $num_qk){
        if($result_incBig < $endRowBig){
            for($e=0;$e<=($endRowBig-$result_incBig);++$e){
                $b .= '<td class="td_formTitle_noBorder" align="center" style="padding:0px; text-indent: 0;" width="165" height="115" valign="bottom"><!--space--></td>'; 
            }
            $b .= '</tr>';  
            $result_incBig = 0;
        }
    }
    //increment inc 
    ++$result_incBig;
    /*END BIG*/

    /*SMALL*/
    //begin new row
    if($result_incSmall == $beginRowSmall){
        $s .= '<tr>';   
        //row color
        $row_color = ($color_incSmall % 2) ? 'tdAltRow_A' : 'tdAltRow_B';
        if($i == ($num_qk-1)){
            $secondRowClass = 'tdAltRow_noBorder';
        }else{
            $secondRowClass = 'tdAltRow';
        }
        //increment the color of the row
        ++$color_incSmall;              
    }
    $s .= '<td class="td_formTitle_noBorder" align="center" style="padding:0px; text-indent: 0;" width="165" height="115" valign="bottom">';
        $s .= '<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">';
            $s .= '<tr>';
                $s .= '<td align="center" style="height:80px; padding:4px; vertical-align:middle;">'.$appendLinkBegin.$companyPic.$appendLinkEnd.'</td>';
            $s .= '</tr>';
            $s .= '<tr>';
                $s .= '<td align="center" style="height:35px; padding:2px; vertical-align:bottom;">'.$appendLinkBegin.'<b>'.$company_name.'</b>'.$addSpace.'<br />'.$num2.' '.$resultText.$appendLinkEnd.'</td>';
            $s .= '</tr>';
        $s .= '</table>';
    $s .= '</td>';
    //end row if out of results or reached max num for row
    if($result_incSmall == $endRowSmall){
        $s .= '</tr>';
        $result_incSmall = 0;
    }else if(($i+1) == $num_qk){
        if($result_incSmall < $endRowSmall){
            for($e=0;$e<=($endRowSmall-$result_incSmall);++$e){
                $s .= '<td class="td_formTitle_noBorder" align="center" style="padding:0px; text-indent: 0;" width="165" height="115" valign="bottom"><!--space--></td>'; 
            }
            $s .= '</tr>';  
            $result_incSmall = 0;
        }
    }
    //increment inc 
    ++$result_incSmall;
    /*END SMALL*/
}
//display table
if($where == ''){
    $b = '<input type="hidden" name="numberRes" id="numberRes" value="No Results" />';
    $s = '<input type="hidden" name="numberRes" id="numberRes" value="No Results" />';
}   
echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">';
    //results
    echo '<div class="rowFillBig">big7Results'.$b.'</div>';
    echo '<div class="rowFillSmall" style="display:none;">small5Results'.$s.'</div>';
echo '</table>';
```

The Jquery function:

```
$(function () {
    $('#tab_1').click(function(){
        $('#tab_vid').toggle();
        if ($("#mainContentRF").width() == 825){
            $("#mainContentRF").width(1180);
            $("audio").width(800);
            //if viewing the full screen pause video
            <?php if($viewingVideo > ''){ ?>
            video = $('.videoplayer').get(0);
            video.pause();
            <?php } ?>
            <!--hide small-->
            $(".rowFillSmall").css("display", "none");
            <!--show big-->
            $(".rowFillBig").css("display", "inline");
        }else{
            $("#mainContentRF").width(825);
            $("audio").width(500);
            <!--show small-->
            $(".rowFillSmall").css("display", "inline");
            <!--hide big-->
            $(".rowFillBig").css("display", "none");
        }
    <!--if tab was left open dont close it-->
    <?php if($acc_openValue_1 == '99'){ ?>
        })
    <?php }else{ ?>
        }).click();
    <?php } ?>
});
```

If I can be more clear please let me know. Basically the div and any content inside should hide when asked to, and show when asked.

Comment: It's very confusing to try and understand someone else's PHP. Since this sounds like your question is actually an HTML and jQuery question (doesn't really pertain to PHP), can you show us the final HTML that is being generated?

Answer (score 0):

Place the div's on the outside of the table like this.

```
    echo '<div class="rowFillBig">';    
    echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">';
        //results
        echo $b;
    echo '</table>';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="rowFillSmall" style="display:none;">';
    echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">';
        //results
        echo $s;
    echo '</table>';
echo '</div>';
```